# openpyxl save without formats, python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am getting an error when saving information in an excel sheet, I carry out the exercise of loading the workbook and I specify the sheet in which I will save the information and finally I use the .save method, this effectively saves the information I want but leaves me the raw file, as shown in the images

I am using version: openpyxl 3.0.10

```
def AsignacionUEM():          
    print("Cargando libro")    
    lPCartera = openpyxl.load_workbook("D:/PLANTILLA/PLANTILLA.xlsm",read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
    print("Cargando hoja")
    hPCartera = lPCartera.worksheets[10]
    print("Agregando registros")
    for row in expAsig:
        hPCartera.append(row)

    print("Guardando excel . . .")
    lPCartera.save("D:/PLANTILLA/PLANTILLA_Envio.xlsm")
    lPCartera.close()
```

*** Excel file with the formats before manipulating it with openpyxl ***

[My Excel before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFDXg.png)

Excel file as a result of having manipulated it with openpxyl, this does save the information, but it leaves it without formats.

[My Excel later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72089.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nrdj.png)

Comment: Although the code is adding some unknown data to the end of the sheet; You are stating that the borders, fill, number format (possibly other styles) are being lost  after effectively opening then saving the file with a new name. I could see that happening if you were copying the sheet to another workbook but not saving a workbook with a different name.

Comment: In the current project, which is a script, I noticed this behavior, but when I validated the same thing began to happen to me in other scripts that I had already done.
repeating the same behavior as saving the obvious information in the formats with which it was previously loaded in the load_workbook method.
I have tried to save it with another name and indeed the new book does not have formats, but the previous one does.
I don't know if this has to do with the fact that the file is xlsm, as I have seen in the documentation this is transparent for this library